# /dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_main at 100%

Tags: server

I get this using `df -h`:

```
root@server:/home/username# df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_main   39G   39G     0 100% /
udev                         993M  4.0K  993M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        401M  264K  401M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        1002M     0 1002M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                    453M   30M  401M   7% /boot
```

I have tried purge, automremove etc. What is `/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_main` and how do I clear it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_main` the name of the logical volume where your root filesystem is located.

At first, I would suspect a log file keeping growing rapidly or a lack of log rotation. (logs are in `/var/log`).

What you can do is to run the command :

```
$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 -x /
```

this will show the size of each directories immediately below /.
In the output, look for a directory with big amount of date.
The repeat the `du` command on this directory (replacing `/` by the name of this directory, e.g.: `/var`) to find which sub-dir is big.

This will avoid to do a full scan of the root filesystem, which can be very long.

Once you identify a directory with using a lot of space, go and see what's in it.

Comment: `/home/root/secret/app/fixtures/secret_data.json`

Comment: It was a log file in the /tmp folder that was responsible. Thanks.

Comment: In my case it was `/var/cache/yum`, to clean it I ran `rm -rf /var/cache/yum`